# ¿Qué es la clase singleton en QT? y cuestiones sobre esta clase

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo una dudas sobre esta clase. Con la clase singleton se puede incorporar objetos sin necesidad de llamarlos emitiendo la instancia singleton. Alguien conoce más sobre esta clase o puede hacer un ejemplo sencillo para que entienda mejor su función?

Comment: "*Con la clase singleton se puede incorporar objetos sin necesidad de llamarlos emitiendo la instancia singleton*", no entiendo qué es esto ¿Puedes reformularlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Respecto al Singleton.

Un Singleton es un objeto que permite la existencia de una única [instancia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instancia_(inform%C3%A1tica)). La mayoría de lenguajes de programación no disponen de Singletons de manera nativa<sup>1</sup>, así que usan los constructos de que disponen para crearlos.

El [Singleton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton), por otro lado, es un [patrón de diseño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o) que no goza de gran popularidad y es considerado como un [anti-patrón de diseño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipatr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o) no porque sea intrínsecamente maligno si no porque se suele usar mal o en situaciones en que no es necesario y suele complicar el código (sobre todo en situaciones de [concurrencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrencia_(inform%C3%A1tica))) y los test asociados al mismo. Además, un Singleton es parecido a una [variable global](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_global) lo cuál sí que está considerado una mala práctica.

### Singleton en Qt.

Qt no dispone de una clase Singleton como parte de sus facilidades, pero da [una guía](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_thread-safe_singleton) para crear una usando sus propias facilidades:

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& instance()
    {
        qCallOnce(init, flag);
        return *tptr;
    }

    static void init()
    {
        tptr.reset(new T);
    }

private:
    Singleton() {};
    ~Singleton() {};
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Singleton)

    static QScopedPointer<T> tptr;
    static QBasicAtomicInt flag;
};
```

La plantilla anterior es un [adaptador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) para transformar en Singleton un objeto arbitrario; requiere llamar a la función estática `instance()` (algo común en implementaciones de Singletons) la cuál delega en la función plantilla `qCallOnce`:

```
template <class Function>
inline static void qCallOnce(Function func, QBasicAtomicInt& flag)
{
    int protectFlag = flag.fetchAndStoreAcquire(flag.load());

    if (protectFlag == CO_Finished)
        return;
    if (protectFlag == CO_Request && flag.testAndSetRelaxed(protectFlag,
                                                       CO_InProgress)) {
        func();
        flag.fetchAndStoreRelease(CO_Finished);
    }
    else {
        do {
            QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
        }
        while (!flag.testAndSetAcquire(CO_Finished, CO_Finished));
    }
}
```

Cuya misión es asegurar que la función pasada como parámetro plantilla sea llamada una vez y sólo una, incluso desde diferentes hilos (gracias  Peregring-lk). El ejemplo de uso de este Singleton sugerido por el equipo de Qt es el siguiente:

```
struct mi_objeto { void f() { std::cout << this << '\n'; } };

Singleton<mi_objeto>::instance().f();
mi_objeto &mo = Singleton<mi_objeto>::instance();
mo.f();
```

El código anterior mostrará dos veces la misma dirección de memoria pues en ambas ocasiones hemos accedido a la misma instancia de `mi_objeto`; pero esta aproximación no nos impedirá hacer instancias adicionales de `mi_objeto` sin usar el Singleton:

```
Singleton<mi_objeto>::instance().f(); // Accedemos al Singleton
mi_objeto &mo = Singleton<mi_objeto>::instance(); // Referenciamos el Singleton
mi_objeto a, b, c, d, e; // Creamos 5 instancias adicionales de mi_objeto
mo.f();
```

Así que `mi_objeto` no será un Singleton, pero `Singleton<mi_objeto>` sí que lo será.

### Singleton en C++.

La aproximación de Qt no es la única para crear un Singleton, desde C++11 es relativamente sencillo crear una clase que se comporte como un Singleton.

#### Clase Singleton.

```
class Neo_The_Chosen_One // Solo puede haber uno!!
{
    static Neo_The_Chosen_One singleton;

public:
    Neo_The_Chosen_One(Neo_The_Chosen_One &&) = delete;
    Neo_The_Chosen_One(const Neo_The_Chosen_One &) = delete;
    Neo_The_Chosen_One &operator=(const Neo_The_Chosen_One &) = delete;

    static Neo_The_Chosen_One &instance()
    {
        return singleton;
    }
};

Neo_The_Chosen_One Neo_The_Chosen_One::singleton{};
```

El código anterior permite una y solo una instancia de el objeto `Neo_The_Chosen_One`, dado que su constructor es privado y tiene borrados el constructor de copia/movimiento y el operador de copia, todos estos usos serían incorrectos:

```
// Error, constructor privado.
Neo_The_Chosen_One mr_anderson_1;
// Error, constructor de copia borrado.
Neo_The_Chosen_One mr_anderson_2 { Neo_The_Chosen_One::instance() };
// Error, operador de copia borrado.
Neo_The_Chosen_One mr_anderson_3 = Neo_The_Chosen_One::instance();
```

Los siguientes usos serían correctos:

```
Neo_The_Chosen_One &mr_anderson_4 { Neo_The_Chosen_One::instance() };
Neo_The_Chosen_One &mr_anderson_5 = Neo_The_Chosen_One::instance();
```

Las referencias `mr_anderson_4` y `mr_anderson_5` apuntarán a la misma instancia (la única permitida) y por ello será peligrosa de usar en sistemas concurrentes.

Pero si no nos importa que pueda existir más de una instancia de la misma clase (y los problemas de concurrencia) podemos usar una variable plantilla o la cláusula [`extern`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) con los mismos resultados y con menos código:

#### Singleton variable plantilla.

```
struct mi_objeto { void f() { std::cout << this << '\n'; } };
template <int DUMMY = 0> mi_objeto objeto;
```

La variable plantilla `objeto` funciona como un Singleton (sólo habrá una instancia de objeto por cada valor `DUMMY`) y se puede usar como los Singleton que ya hemos visto:

```
mi_objeto &mo { objeto<> };
mo.f();
objeto<>.f();
```

Esta aproximación tiene la *peculiaridad* de que podemos tener varios Singleton de `mi_objeto` por cada valor que le demos al parametro plantilla `DUMMY`, esto se debe a la regla de definición única de C++ y cómo esta regla funciona con las plantillas, según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (resaltado y traducción mías):

> #### 3.2 Regla de definición única
>
> 5. **Se requiere exáctamente una definición de una clase en una unidad de traducción** si dicha clase es usada de manera que su tipo necesite estar completo.
>
>    [...]
> 6. **Puede haber más de una definición** del tipo de una clase (Cláusula 9), tipo enumerado (7.2), función en línea con enlazado externo (7.1.2), clase plantilla (Cláusula 14), función plantilla no estática (14.5.6), datos miembro de una clase plantilla (14.5.1.3), función miembro de una clase plantilla (14.5.1.1), o especialización de plantilla para la que algunos parámetros plantilla no están especificados (14.7, 14.5.5) **en un programa en que cada definición aparezca en diferentes unidades de traducción**, [...]
>
>    [...]
>
>    **Si D es una plantilla y se define en más de una unidad de traducción,** [...], **entonces se comportará como si hubiera una única definición de D**.

#### Singleton variable global.

El Singleton se comporta como una variable global (por eso se gana tantos enemigos) así que una variable global en esencia, es un Singleton. Podemos conseguir las características de un Singleton usando el calificador `extern`:

```
// mi_objeto.hpp
struct mi_objeto { void f() { std::cout << this << '\n'; } };
```

```
// mi_objeto.cpp
mi_objeto singleton{};
```

```
// Archivo1.hpp
#include "mi_objeto.hpp"
extern mi_objeto singleton;
```

```
// Archivo2.hpp
#include "mi_objeto.hpp"
extern mi_objeto singleton;
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la instancia de `mi_objeto` llamada `singleton` se comportará como un Singleton; es decir: tanto `Archivo1.hpp` como `Archivo2.hpp` accederán a la misma instancia de `mi_objeto` llamada `singleton`; para que esto funcione todas las declaraciones de `singleton` tienen que ser `extern` excepto una (si no obtendremos un error de enlazado).

---

<sup>1</sup>El único que conozco que de sporte nativo a singleton es [Kotlin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n)).

Comment: No has dejado claro que el objetivo es `qCallOnce` es que la función sea llamada solo una vez desde el punto de vista de hilos concurrentes que intentar llamar a la función al mismo tiempo. `qCallOnce` se asegura que la función solo sea ejecutada una vez, no desde el punto de vista de un mismo hilo que llama dos veces, sino de varios hilos que intentan llamar a la vez, evitando la posibilidad de se creen dos instancias en vez de una de manera concurrente (una alternativa al double-checked locking, pero con *memory guards*).

Comment: @Peregring-lk tienes razón, también me falta hablar de los tipos de inicialización de Singletons (perezosa, estática...) de Singletons existentes en C++ (`cout` y `cin`), de otros objetos que se comportan como Singleton (objetos con todos los miembros y métodos estáticos o que adaptan datos en espacio estático) pero me salía una respuesta larguísima que ni siquiera se si responde a la duda de Omar Alami (pues no entiendo del todo su pregunta) así que decidí no alargarme más.

Comment: `cout` y `cin`, no son singletones, son objetos globales.

Comment: @Peregring-lk ¿En qué se diferencia un objeto global (accesible desde cualquier punto y del que sólo existe una copia) de un Singleton (objeto del que sólo existe una copia)?

Comment: en que el singletón asegura que solo exista una instancia de esa clase, sin embargo, puedo tener varios objetos de tipo `std::ostream` (e `std::istream`). Eso sí, instancias diferentes porque tienen la copia deshabilitada, pero más de una instancia, al fin y al cabo .

Comment: @Peregring-lk entonces el Singleton propuesto por el equipo de Qt (y varios de los Singleton que he mencionado) tampoco serían Singleton. Si admitimos por otro lado que pueden existir más de una instancia de un `std::ostream` entonces `std::cout` sería un SIngleton de tipo `std::ostream`.

Comment: La plantilla `Singleton` que has puesto arriba, la que contiene la llamada a `qCallOnce`, es un singletón de acuerdo de mi definición. No se permite más de una instancia de la clase (el contructor es privado, el constructor de `std::ostream`, sin embargo, es público).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47119/discussion-between-paperbirdmaster-and-peregring-lk).

Answer (score 4):

Singleton es un patrón de diseño, su idea es que exista una sola instancia de ese objeto en cuestión y pueda utilizarse globalmente sin permitir crear una instancia nuevamente. Para evitar que otras clases creen instancias se ocupan los modificadores de accesos protected y private.

Te voy a dejar un link de un PDF en español que explica detalladamente en que consiste con `qt

[Pdf Singleton + QT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jZajCaNpwaVXBMeTQ3azltRUU/view)`

Answer (score 1):

Es una clase que solo adminte una instancia. El ejemplo mas comun es la clase `QApplication`.

Solo podemos hacer `QApplication app;` y para acceder a la unica instancia(Patron "Singleton") usamos `QApplication::instance()`en cualquier parte de nuestra codigo y retorna el puntero a la unica instancia.