# Cómo usar opciones de un menú, en un menú ajeno a ese

Tags: c++, nodejs, array, lista

**Actividad escolar.**

*Creó la pregunta no se explica bien en lo que necesito ayuda.*

Tengo dos clases que funcionan como menús, una crea un nodos, el nodo(civilización) tiene un arreglo el cual tiene espacios para el nombre y datos sobre aldeanos.
La otra crea todo lo referente al aldeano, el nombre, la vida, todo.
Lo que necesito es que al buscar un nodo(el cual tiene el nombre de una civilización) mande a llamar al segundo menú para crear el aldeano y después meterlo en el arreglo con el respectivo nodo.

*El enlace al repo es el siguiente:* [GITHUB](https://github.com/ChikenGamer/GameID)

El primer menú de aldeanos se llama menu.cpp
Y el segundo menucivilizacion.cpp
El menú de aldeanos es el siguiente:

```
#include "menu.h"
#include "menucivilizacion.h"
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"

Menu::Menu()
{
    string op;
    Aldeano a;///Para el aldeano
    Civilizacion<Aldeano> arr;///Para el arreglo no con punteros

    ///Opciones del menu
    //cout << endl << "1) Agregar nombre a la civilizacion" << endl;
    cout << "1) Agregar aldeano" << endl;
    cout << "2) Eliminar aldeano " << endl;
    cout << "3) Resumen" << endl;
    cout << "0) Salir" << endl;
    cout << "Opcion: "; getline(cin, op);
    system("cls");

    if (op == "1") {
        ///Se piden los datos para el aldeano
        int myInt;
        string myStr;
        cout << "Ingresa el nombre: ";
        getline(cin, myStr);
        a.setNombreA(myStr);

        cout << "Ingresa la edad: ";
        cin >> myInt;
        a.setEdadA(myInt);

        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Ingresa el genero (H/M): ";
        getline(cin, myStr);
        if (myStr == "H" or myStr == "M") {
            ///Si se ingresa una H o una M se setea el genero
            a.setGeneroA(myStr);
        }else{
            ///Si se ingresa algo diferente de H o M se cancela
            cout << endl << "-=ERROR: UTILIZA H O M" << endl << endl;
            continue;
        }

        cout << "Ingresa la salud (HP): ";
        cin >> myInt;
        a.setSaludA(myInt);
        cin.ignore();
        ///Se agrega el aldeano al arreglo
        arr.agregarA(a);

    }else if (op == "2") {

        string myStr;
        int pos;
        if(arr.isEmpty()){
            ///Si el arreglo esta vacío no es posible eliminar aldeanos, se sigue con el menu
            cout << "-=ERROR: NO HAY ALDEANOS PARA ELIMINAR=-" << endl << endl;
            continue;
        }
        ///Si no esta vacío se pide el nombre del aldeano y se hace la busqueda
        cout << "Ingresa el nombre del aldeano a eliminar: ";
        getline(cin, myStr);
        a.setNombreA(myStr);
        pos = arr.linearFindData(a);
        if(pos == -1){
            ///Si la busqueda regresa -1 el adeano no existe
            cout << endl << "-=ERROR: EL ALDEANO NO EXISTE-=" << endl << endl;
        }else{
            ///El aldeano existe, preguntar si desea eliminarlo
            string op;
            cout << "Estas seguro de eliminar a '" << myStr << "'? S/N: ";
            getline(cin, op);
            if(op == "S"){
                ///Si dice que sí se elimina al aldeano y se envia la confirmación
                arr.eliminarA(pos);
                cout << endl << "-=ALDEANO ELIMINADO=-" << endl << endl;
            }else if(op == "N"){
                ///Si dice que no el aldeano vuelve "a su hogar" y se sigue con el menu
                cout << endl << "-=EL ALDEANO VOLVIO A SU HOGAR=-" << endl << endl;
                continue;
            }else{
                ///Si se usa una letra diferente de 'S' o 'N'
                cout << endl << "-=ERROR: OPCION NO VALIDA=-" << endl << endl;
            }
        }
[...]
```

El menú de la civilización con punteros y nodos:

```
#include "menucivilizacion.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"
#include "lista.h"

MenuCivilizacion::MenuCivilizacion()
{
    string op;

    Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano>*> list;

    Civilizacion<Aldeano>* pos;

    while (true) {
        //Opciones del menu
        cout << "1) Agregar nueva civilizacion" << endl;
        cout << "2) Buscar civilizacion" << endl;
        cout << "3) Eliminar civilizacion" << endl;
        cout << "4) Mostrar civilizaciones" << endl;
        cout << "Opcion: "; getline(cin, op);
        system("cls");

    if (op=="1") {
        /* Agregar civilizacion
         * Creara un objeto apuntador de la clase "civilizacion"
         */

        string myStr;
        cout << "Ingresa el nombre de la nueva civilizacion: ";
        getline(cin, myStr);
        if (list.posValida(myStr)) {
            cout << endl << "-=ERROR: YA EXISTE UNA CIVILIZACION CON EL NOMBRE=-" << endl << endl;
            continue;
        }
        Civilizacion<Aldeano> *c = new Civilizacion<Aldeano>;
        c->setNombreC(myStr);
        list.insertarIn(c);

        cout << endl << "-=CIVILIZACION CREADA=-" << endl << endl;


    }else if(op=="2"){
        /*
         * Buscar civilizacion
         * pedira el nombre de una civilizacíon, si la civilizacion no
         * existe, mostrar un mensaje. Si existe la civilizacion,
         * mostrar el menu de la actividad 01
         */
        string myStr;

        cout << "Nombre de la civilizacion a buscar: ";
        getline(cin, myStr);



        if (list.posValida(myStr)) {//Que hacer si existe la civilizacion
            pos = list.findData(myStr);
            Menu m; //Otro menú 
**Aquí llamo al otro menú, donde creo el aldeano, una vez creado lo inserto en el array, pero cómo?**
        }else{
            cout << endl<< "-=ERROR: LA CIVILIZACION NO EXISTE=-" << endl << endl;
        }

    }else if (op=="3") {
        /*Eliminar civilizacion
         * Pedira el nombre de la civilizacion y eliminara el nodo de la lista
         * simplemente ligada que corresponda a la civilizacion con ese nombre
         */
        string myStr,op;

        cout << "Nombre de la civilizacion a eliminar: ";
        getline(cin, myStr);
        if (list.posValida(myStr)) {
            cout << "Estas seguro de eliminar la civilizacion '" << myStr << "' ? S/N: ";
            getline(cin, op);
            if (op == "S" or op == "s") {
                list.eliminarCiv(myStr);
                cout << endl << "-=CIVILIZACION ELIMINADA=-" << endl;
                cout << endl << "-=CIVILIZACIONES RESTANTES: " << list.tamano() << " =-" << endl<< endl;
            }else{
                cout << endl << "-=LA CIVILIZACION SOBREVIVIO AL ATENTADO=-" << endl << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "-=ERROR: LA CIVILIZACION NO EXISTE=-";
        }
[...]
```

**Error de singleton**
`error: 'singleton<Civilizacion<Aldeano> >' does not name a type
 using Aldeano = singleton<Civilizacion<Aldeano>>;
                 ^`
`error: 'singleton<Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano>*> >' does not name a type
 using Civilizacion = singleton<Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano> *>>;
                      ^`

Básicamente cómo creo un aldeano con el otro menú y lo meto en el arreglo del nodo del segundo menú.

**Gracias**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Básicamente cómo creo un aldeano con el otro menú y lo meto en el arreglo del nodo del segundo menú.

Has dado con un problema habitual en el tipo de aplicaciones que estás desarrollando. Mi elección **personal** para encarar estos problemas es utilizar un [singleton](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/28532/qu%C3%A9-es-la-clase-singleton-en-qt-y-cuestiones-sobre-esta-clase) o diseñar un gestor.

#### Propuesta singleton.

Mi forma preferida de crear singletons es usando variables plantilla, en tu caso crearía una cabecera nueva que ofreciera la funcionalidad singleton:

`singleton.hpp`

```
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"

template <typename T>
T singleton{};

using Aldeanos = singleton<Civilizacion<Aldeano>>;
using Civilizaciones = singleton<Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano> *>>;
```

Toda instancia de `singleton<tipo>` será única en todo el programa, por ello en cualquier punto de tu programa en que incluyas `"singleton.hpp"` podrás acceder a los singleton `Aldeanos` o `Civilizaciones` que serán una única instancia global de `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` y `Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano> *>` respectivamente.

#### Propuesta gestor.

Un gestor de datos es una interfaz a ciertos datos que ofrece operaciones de gestión de dichos datos, en tu caso parece que necesitas un gestor de `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` y otro de `Civilizacion<Aldeano> *`, a tu criterio queda el diseño para que se ajuste a tus necesidades, lo más sencillo que se me ocurre es:

`gestor_aldeanos.hpp`

```
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"

Civilizacion<Aldeanos> &GetAldeanos();
```

`gestor_aldeanos.hpp`

```
#include "gestor_aldeanos.hpp"

namespace {
Civilizacion<Aldeanos> c; // innacesible desde fuera
}

Civilizacion<Aldeanos> &GetAldeanos() {
    return c;
}
```

`gestor_civilizaciones.cpp`

```
#include "civilizacion.h"
#include "aldeano.h"
#include "lista"

Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeanos> *> &GetCivilizaciones();
```

`gestor_civilizaciones.cpp`

```
#include "gestor_civilizaciones.hpp"

namespace {
Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeanos> *> c; // innacesible desde fuera
}

Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeanos> *> &GetCivilizaciones() {
    return c;
}
```

El código anterior permite que en cualquier punto de tu programa en que incluyas `"gestor_aldeanos.hpp"` podrás llamar a `GetAldeanos()` que te proporcionará una instancia única de `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` y si incluyes `"gestor_civilizaciones.hpp"` podrás llamar a `GetCivilizaciones()` que te proporcionará una instancia única de `Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano> *>`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

No me parece que tu código sea funcional en ningún aspecto; ¿pueden existir `Civilizacion` que no sean de `Aldeano`?<sup>1</sup> Creo que estás confundiendo colecciones de aldeanos con civilizaciones... y de ser así, funcionalmente `Civilizacion<Aldeano>` y `Lista<Civlizacion<Aldeano> *>` serán lo mismo.

---

1. ¿Civilizaciones de `int`, de `std::string` o de `Alpargata`?

Comment: Cómo haces para llamar a singleton? como singleton<Aldeanos>?, me aparece un error `singleton<Civilizacion<Aldeano> >' does not name a type
 using Aldeanos = singleton<Civilizacion<Aldeano>>;` Al hacer esto el arreglo termina siendo el mismo?, la idea es que toda civilización y aldeano este y se obtenga de la lista ligada. `Lista<Civilizacion<Aldeano>*> list;`, mediante la c definida aquí eh notado que puedo acceder a insertar un aldeano pero necesito el otro menú para crearlo `Civilizacion<Aldeano> *c = new Civilizacion<Aldeano>;`. Posteo el error de singleton. @Paula_plus_plus , gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, con funcional a que te refieres?, funciona, de alguna manera hace todo menos lo que me falta sobre lo de los menús. Y sí, puede existir civilizaciones de enteros strings y demás

Comment: Según el código que he compartido, para llamar al singleton de un objeto arbitrario debes escribir `singleton<tipo>`, mientras incluyas `"singleton.hpp"` el `singleton<tipo>` será el mismo en todos lados. Por funcionalmente me refiero a que tienen la misma función como un coche y una camioneta funcionalmente son para lo mismo (moverse a uno mismo y otros objetos entre diferentes puntos) aunque concretamente no sean iguales.

Comment: Muchas gracias!